# column view doesn't tabulate all headings and it modifies buffer in org mode

Tags: org-mode

Running column view (`C-c C-x C-c`) shouldn't change buffer at all. However, in some cases, I found it adds extra whitespaces in some locations in the buffer. In the example in the snapshot, the column view, for unknown reason, did not tabulate the heading `Known Issues` and it modified the buffer (the 3 whitespaces added after the heading as I show in red in the git diff in the screenshot). Does anyone know why column view doesn't tabulate all headings and why it modifies a buffer? This is very undesirable.

[image]

[image]

The org file is available here for testing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj5vnzpn3ls4pd2/foo2.org?dl=0

And I am using:

- Org mode version 9.3.6 (9.3.6-25-g685b2c-elpa @ /Users/john/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20200330/)
- GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02
- Mac OS Catalina

Comment: What about reporting the bug?

Answer (score 2):

While I wasn't able to solve this, here are some significant observations:

#### tabulated headline is there, it's just hidden

`C-c C-x C-c` and then expanding "*** Math" (the very last headline before "* Known Issues") shows that there *is* a tabulated headline for "Known Issues" - it is just 2 lines obve the actual headline (which is obviously a bug).

#### minimal example

I created a minimal example file to reproduce the error:

```
something
* A
* X
```

Stunningly the error only occurs when the second headline is *at least as long* as the one before it.

Works as expected:

```
something
* AB
* X
```

Broken:

```
something
* A
* X
```

```
something
* A
* XY
```

#### Workaround

Repeating `C-c C-x C-c` fixes the problem (although this is not a great solution).